# What is the iOS auto_return timeout for the Square POS API?

Tags: square-connect, point-of-sale, square

In the [Android URL parameters](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/web-technical-reference#android-url-parameters) section, the [Point of Sale API - Mobile Web Technical Reference](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/web-technical-reference) explicitly specifies the possible auto return timeout to be within the range of 3200 to 10000 milliseconds.  The [iOS additional payment options](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/web-technical-reference#specifying-additional-payment-options) section only defines the auto return timeout to be a "short timeout".  Is the iOS timeout within the same time range as Android or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *auto_return* timeout for iOS is **2** seconds. I also want to note that it's subject to change, but unlikely.